# ggplot: modify coord_cartesian() values dynamically

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to modify the plot coordinates using coord_cartesian() in a way that is dynamic based on the data in the ggplot call?

For example:

```
ggplot(cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) + 
geom_point() + 
coord_cartesian(xlim = c(min(.$speed), max(.$speed) + 10))
```

This doesn't work, nor does using `.data$speed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `magrittr` and `dplyr` pipe operator (`%>%`) to pass data into the ggplot call.

```
cars %>%
  {ggplot(., aes(speed, dist)) + 
     geom_point() + 
     coord_cartesian(xlim = c(min(.$speed), max(.$speed) + 10))
  }
```

Note that now you need to explicitly identify the data argument at the beginning of the ggplot call using the `.` pronoun.

Comment: is it possible to adjust this for dual axis plots? I added another ``coord_cartesian`` line for the second variable but it the graph cuts off

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit hacky but you can add a blank geom and add 10 to the y in the aesthetics.

```
ggplot(cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_blank(aes(y = dist + 10))
```