Setting Limits in a geom_bar() ggplot
I am running a series of ggplot() calls to create weekly breakdowns of fantasy baseball matchups for various categories. These use geom_bar(). It currently looks like this:

The problem is that I would like this OBP (on base percentage) plot to be considerably narrower in view--in other words, instead of a x-axis minimum value of 0, having an x-axis minimum value of .259 (the smallest value in the dataset for OBP).
However, when I add a limits call to scale_x_continuous(), it gives a warning of "Removed 12 rows containing missing values (geom_bar)." Code is below. Any ideas on how to set an axis limit while using geom_bar()?
  dta2 <- subset(dta1,Category=="OBP")
  obpmin <- min(dta2$Count)
  obpmax <- max(dta2$Count)
  OBP <- ggplot(dta2,aes(x=Count,y=reorder(Team_Opp,Count),fill=WLD))+
    geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity")+
eval(parse(text=paste("scale_x_continuous(expand=expansion(0,0),limits=c(",obpmin,",",obpmax,"))",sep="")))+
    theme_bw()+
    theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5),
          panel.grid.major.y=element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank())+
    scale_fill_manual(name="",
                      values=c("Win" = "#56B4E9",
                               "Draw" = "#009E73",
                               "Loss" = "#D55E00"))+
    xlab("OBP")+
    ylab("")

The issue does not seem to relate to the use of obpmin and obpmax, since even when I enter the limits manually (code below), it gives the warning message that it removed the 12 bars for containing missing values.
OBP <- ggplot(dta2,aes(x=Count,y=reorder(Team_Opp,Count),fill=WLD))+
    geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity")+
    scale_x_continuous(expand=expansion(0,0),limits=c(.259,.362))+
    theme_bw()+
    theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5),
          panel.grid.major.y=element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank())+
    scale_fill_manual(name="",
                      values=c("Win" = "#56B4E9",
                               "Draw" = "#009E73",
                               "Loss" = "#D55E00"))+
    xlab("OBP")+
    ylab("")


Try + coord_cartesian(xlim=c(.259,.362)) How to set limits for axes in ggplot2 R plots?

Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45555095/ggplot-modify-coord-cartesian-values-dynamically

@Edward thanks so much--that did the trick for me. Appreciate the quick response.

[The reason setting the limits using scale_x_continuous gives you unexpected results is that geom_bar covers a range of values from either end of the bar; the limits in that function will exclude any data that is not entirely within those limits, i.e. any bar that starts or ends outside them. coord_cartesian does not filter the data itself, so is a better choice here.] https://r4ds.had.co.nz/graphics-for-communication.html?q=limits#zooming
